# How to avoid returning of deleted code after merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-flow

In our team we struggle with such situations:

1. Two or more developers create branches from current `develop`.
2. One of them deletes some code and pushes.
3. Lead merges this branch to `develop`.
4. The other developer pushes his branch.
5. Lead merges this branch to `develop`.
6. Code, which first developer deleted, returns.

How to avoid it?

Options I see:

- Before `push` each developer should pull updated version of `develop` and merge it into his local branch.
- Using git-flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

- Lead merges this branch to develop.
- Code, which first developer deleted, returns.

A merge does not restore deleted code unless it is being done in a very strange way (e.g. by copying files manually).

If Developer A makes a change which is "Delete code X" and Developer B makes some other change, merging the two does not restore X.  If that's happening you'll need to analyze in much more detail the workflow of the person doing the merge, and of course you can view in detail all the commits in the main repo now.

Comment: I supposed that as developer B didn't even touch deleted code git, em..., git thinks that some new code arrived and it should be added to develop. I mean, in developer B branch that deleted in developer A code exists. According to your answer it's not correct.

Comment: @RamilMuratov: A merge is not "overwrite our files with the new files."  It is "take the specific changes and apply them."  If Developer B doesn't have Developer A's deletions, that's fine, because if you start with "MNOPQ" and Developer A says "delete N" and Developer B says "add R", you end up with "MOPQR" - "N" does not return when Developer B's instructions are applied.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know. I'll dig in our workflow.